# Hybris error with Spring-Loaded

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, hotdeploy, spring-loaded

I am using [**Spring-Loaded**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) to realize hot deployment in **Hybris** project, but there are some errors. And I am using **Java Service Wrapper**.

Start server with command `hybrisserver.bat debug`

**wrapper-debug.conf** segment:

```
wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre/bin/java

wrapper.java.additional.1=-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Xms1024M
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Xmx2048M
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Xmn800M
wrapper.java.additional.5=-XX:MaxPermSize=400M
wrapper.java.additional.6=-ea
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
wrapper.java.additional.9=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
wrapper.java.additional.10=-Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=true
wrapper.java.additional.11=-Djava.endorsed.dirs="%CATALINA_HOME%/lib/endorsed"
wrapper.java.additional.11.stripquotes=TRUE
wrapper.java.additional.12=-Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE%
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME%
wrapper.java.additional.14=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
wrapper.java.additional.15=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j_init_tomcat.properties
wrapper.java.additional.16=-Djava.util.logging.config.file=jdk_logging.properties
wrapper.java.additional.17=-Djava.io.tmpdir="C:\XXX"
wrapper.java.additional.17.stripquotes=TRUE
wrapper.java.additional.18=-Duseconfig=
wrapper.java.additional.19=-DHYBRIS_BIN_DIR="C:\XXX"
wrapper.java.additional.19.stripquotes=TRUE
wrapper.java.additional.20=-DHYBRIS_CONFIG_DIR="C:\XXX"
wrapper.java.additional.20.stripquotes=TRUE
wrapper.java.additional.21=-DHYBRIS_DATA_DIR="C:\XXX"
wrapper.java.additional.21.stripquotes=TRUE
wrapper.java.additional.22=-DHYBRIS_LOG_DIR="C:\XXX"
wrapper.java.additional.22.stripquotes=TRUE
wrapper.java.additional.23=-DHYBRIS_TEMP_DIR="C:\XXX"
wrapper.java.additional.23.stripquotes=TRUE
wrapper.java.additional.24=-Xdebug
wrapper.java.additional.25=-Xnoagent
wrapper.java.additional.26=-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n
wrapper.java.additional.27=-Ddeployed.server.type=tomcat
wrapper.java.additional.28=-javaagent:c:/springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
wrapper.java.additional.29=–noverify
```

JVM parameter is

```
wrapper.java.additional.28=-javaagent:c:/springloaded-1.2.5.RELEASE.jar
wrapper.java.additional.29=–noverify
```

When starting server **error** occurred as below:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:51:19.320 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:51:23.905 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultRMIRegistryService] Creating Registry on port 2198.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:51:23.920 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [LocalRMISocketFactory] Creating server socket at '/127.0.0.1:2198'.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:51:26.450 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | wrapper  | main    | 2017/02/08 10:51:40.537 | Wrapper Process has not received any CPU time for 11 seconds.  Extending timeouts.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:51:40.545 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:15.202 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [CacheConfiguration] Cache: igcIgcPromotionsCache has a maxElementsInMemory of 0. This might lead to performance degradation or OutOfMemoryError at Terracotta client.From Ehcache 2.0 onwards this has been changed to mean a store with no capacity limit. Set it to 1 if you want no elements cached in memory
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:15.260 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [CacheConfiguration] Cache: iwaRedemptionProductsWithStockCache has a maxElementsInMemory of 0. This might lead to performance degradation or OutOfMemoryError at Terracotta client.From Ehcache 2.0 onwards this has been changed to mean a store with no capacity limit. Set it to 1 if you want no elements cached in memory
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:15.303 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [CacheConfiguration] Cache: iwaRedemptionProductsWithStockCacheByProduct has a maxElementsInMemory of 0. This might lead to performance degradation or OutOfMemoryError at Terracotta client.From Ehcache 2.0 onwards this has been changed to mean a store with no capacity limit. Set it to 1 if you want no elements cached in memory
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:15.945 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion entityCacheRegion, eviction policy LRU, size 300000
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:15.958 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion queryCacheRegion, eviction policy FIFO, size 20000
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:30.844 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:31.082 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:49.498 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EhCacheCreationStrategy] productPriceCache already exists so can't be created
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:49.709 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EhCacheCreationStrategy] productStockCache already exists so can't be created
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:52:49.857 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EhCacheCreationStrategy] productVariantFullCache already exists so can't be created
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:22.489 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:22.585 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:22.657 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [CacheConfiguration] Cache: daysCache has a maxElementsInMemory of 0. This might lead to performance degradation or OutOfMemoryError at Terracotta client.From Ehcache 2.0 onwards this has been changed to mean a store with no capacity limit. Set it to 1 if you want no elements cached in memory
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:22.711 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [CacheConfiguration] Cache: monthsCache has a maxElementsInMemory of 0. This might lead to performance degradation or OutOfMemoryError at Terracotta client.From Ehcache 2.0 onwards this has been changed to mean a store with no capacity limit. Set it to 1 if you want no elements cached in memory
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:22.753 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [CacheConfiguration] Cache: yearsCache has a maxElementsInMemory of 0. This might lead to performance degradation or OutOfMemoryError at Terracotta client.From Ehcache 2.0 onwards this has been changed to mean a store with no capacity limit. Set it to 1 if you want no elements cached in memory
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:22.802 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [CacheConfiguration] Cache: iwaProductDataCache has a maxElementsInMemory of 0. This might lead to performance degradation or OutOfMemoryError at Terracotta client.From Ehcache 2.0 onwards this has been changed to mean a store with no capacity limit. Set it to 1 if you want no elements cached in memory
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:23.139 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion mediaCacheRegion, eviction policy LFU, size 100000
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:23.158 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion productCacheRegion, eviction policy LFU, size 100000
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:23.177 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion stockAndPriceCacheRegion, eviction policy LFU, size 100000
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:23.195 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion usersCacheRegion, eviction policy LRU, size 50000
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:23.216 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion staticPromotionCacheRegion, eviction policy LFU, size 1000000
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:23.240 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion backendPromotionTagCacheRegion, eviction policy FIFO, size 500
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:23.358 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [EHCacheRegion] EHCacheRegion volatileCartAndPromotionCacheRegion, eviction policy LRU, size 100000
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:24.700 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [IwaPushNotificationObjectMapper] Constructing ObjectMapper for push notification
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:42.823 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [YTypeSystemLoader] You can not modify the typecode of deployment de.hybris.platform.persistence.iwacore_IwaMasterBankPromotion from 25316 to 25304, perform an initialization for that purpose
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:42.882 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [YTypeSystemLoader] You can not modify the typecode of deployment de.hybris.platform.persistence.iwacore_IwaBankPromotion from 25317 to 25301, perform an initialization for that purpose
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:48.805 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Regioncache initialized with region count 10
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:48.827 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: typesystemCacheRegion, size: 0, types: [81, 82, 83, 84, 87], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.UnlimitedCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:48.856 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: entityCacheRegion, size: 300000, types: [__ALL_TYPES__, __NO_QUERY__], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:48.903 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: queryCacheRegion, size: 20000, types: [__QUERY_CACHE__], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:48.934 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: mediaCacheRegion, size: 100000, types: [30, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:48.970 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: productCacheRegion, size: 100000, types: [1, 611, 142, 143], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:48.995 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: stockAndPriceCacheRegion, size: 100000, types: [2007, 2020, 1055, 11026], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:49.023 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: usersCacheRegion, size: 50000, types: [4, 23, 6207, 11037, 11062], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:49.046 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: staticPromotionCacheRegion, size: 1000000, types: [11078, 11076, 11079, 11081, 11075, 11077, 11080, 25001, 25002, 25004], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:49.090 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: backendPromotionTagCacheRegion, size: 500, types: [19075], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:49.215 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Cache region: Name: volatileCartAndPromotionCacheRegion, size: 100000, types: [20001, 12090, 11087, 11113, 11111, 11112, 11095, 11089, 11116, 13780, 12115, 43, 44, 25018, 25011, 12988, 11115], exclusive computation: false, statistics: true, class: class de.hybris.platform.regioncache.region.impl.EHCacheRegion
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:53:49.279 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [DefaultCacheController] Registered Listener on cache controller. Currently registered 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:06.612 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [SolrCoreRegistry] Initializing Solr core components
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:07.183 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:07.253 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:18.135 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [YTypeSystemLoader] You can not modify the typecode of deployment de.hybris.platform.persistence.iwacore_IwaMasterBankPromotion from 25316 to 25304, perform an initialization for that purpose
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:18.159 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [YTypeSystemLoader] You can not modify the typecode of deployment de.hybris.platform.persistence.iwacore_IwaBankPromotion from 25317 to 25301, perform an initialization for that purpose
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:26.384 | INFO  [AfterSaveEventPublisher-master] [DefaultBroadcastService] updating cluster island ID -1->15499695405923344
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:30.759 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:31.073 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:32.204 | INFO  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [JMXBeanLoader] Registered 5 JMX beans for tenant >
INFO   | wrapper  | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:38.322 | Wrapper Process has not received any CPU time for 6 seconds.  Extending timeouts.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:38.331 | INFO  [AfterSaveEventPublisher-master] [DefaultTaskService] Task engine starting up (min:10 max:10 idle:20s interval:10s)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:38.343 | INFO  [Task-master-poll] [DefaultModelConverterRegistry] loading model converters: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:38.353 | INFO  [Task-master-poll] [DefaultModelConverterRegistry]    pre-fetch mode:none
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:38.361 | INFO  [AfterSaveEventPublisher-master] [VjdbcServerWrapper] VJDBC server established successfully 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:38.976 | WARN  [Task-master-poll] [YAttributeDescriptor] Attribute IgcPromotionTag.tag is marked mandatory yet is also a localized attribute. We advise setting its optional field to 'true' to avoid getting errors when a new language is added for which this attribute has no localized value.  See: IgcPromotionTag.tag(localized:java.lang.String):((igccommercecore))::YAttributeDescriptor[igccommercecore-items.xml:1922(AttributeTagListener)][PROPERTY]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:39.086 | WARN  [Task-master-poll] [YAttributeDescriptor] Attribute IwaPromotionBanner.title is marked mandatory yet is also a localized attribute. We advise setting its optional field to 'true' to avoid getting errors when a new language is added for which this attribute has no localized value.  See: IwaPromotionBanner.title(localized:java.lang.String):((iwacore))::YAttributeDescriptor[iwacore-items.xml:3331(AttributeTagListener)][PROPERTY]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:39.131 | WARN  [Task-master-poll] [YAttributeDescriptor] Attribute IwaPromotionBanner.description is marked mandatory yet is also a localized attribute. We advise setting its optional field to 'true' to avoid getting errors when a new language is added for which this attribute has no localized value.  See: IwaPromotionBanner.description(localized:java.lang.String):((iwacore))::YAttributeDescriptor[iwacore-items.xml:3336(AttributeTagListener)][PROPERTY]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:55:39.172 | WARN  [Task-master-poll] [YAttributeDescriptor] Attribute IwaPromotionSimpleBannersComponent.headerTitle is marked mandatory yet is also a localized attribute. We advise setting its optional field to 'true' to avoid getting errors when a new language is added for which this attribute has no localized value.  See: IwaPromotionSimpleBannersComponent.headerTitle(localized:java.lang.String):((iwacore))::YAttributeDescriptor[iwacore-items.xml:3349(AttributeTagListener)][PROPERTY]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:33.032 | INFO  [Task-master-poll] [DefaultTaskService] Polling thread started.
INFO   | wrapper  | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.526 | Wrapper Process has not received any CPU time for 2 seconds.  Extending timeouts.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.537 | ERROR [Task-master-poll] [JDBCValueMappings] could not read serialized value [fieldName=p_defaultvalue] : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hybris.platform.util.ItemPropertyValue
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.567 | ERROR [Task-master-poll] [PropertyJDBC] error reading property field 'defaultValue'/'p_defaultvalue' of item '8796477325399'/'8796477325399'  (info was [defaultValue,p_defaultvalue,class java.lang.Object] ) 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.592 |  stack: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.593 | ERROR [Task-master-poll] [JaloSession] Got exception in notifyExtensionsAfterUserChange
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.609 | de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloSystemException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.hybris.platform.util.ItemPropertyValue[HY--1]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.637 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.PropertyJDBC.readPropertyRow(PropertyJDBC.java:948)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.651 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.PropertyJDBC.getProperties(PropertyJDBC.java:355)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.667 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.property.ItemPropertyCacheKey.computeValue(ItemPropertyCacheKey.java:133)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.683 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.ItemCacheKey.getOrCreateValue(ItemCacheKey.java:101)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.694 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.ItemCacheKey.getValueForReading(ItemCacheKey.java:110)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.711 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.ItemEJB.getCachedValueForReading(ItemEJB.java:603)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.728 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.ExtensibleItemEJB.getPropertyAccessInternal(ExtensibleItemEJB.java:276)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.750 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.ExtensibleItemEJB.getPropertyAccess(ExtensibleItemEJB.java:213)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.764 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.ExtensibleItemEJB.getPropertyFromPropertyAccess(ExtensibleItemEJB.java:517)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.777 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.ExtensibleItemEJB.getPropertyRaw(ExtensibleItemEJB.java:482)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.790 |     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor116.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.798 |     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.810 |     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.816 |     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.842 |     at de.hybris.platform.util.Utilities.callMethod(Utilities.java:1120)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.848 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.framework.RemoteInvocationHandler.performOther(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:190)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.863 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.framework.RemoteInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:107)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.876 |     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.getPropertyRaw(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:35.885 |     at de.hybris.platform.persistence.ExtensibleItemEJBImpl.getProperty(ExtensibleItemEJBImpl.java:101)
..............
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:44.331 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.order.strategies.ordercloning.impl.DefaultOrderPartOfMembersCloningStrategy.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | wrapper  | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:54.395 | Wrapper Process has not received any CPU time for 10 seconds.  Extending timeouts.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:54.407 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'modelService' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setModelService(de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ModelService)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.order.strategies.ordercloning.impl.DefaultOrderPartOfMembersCloningStrategy.setModelService(de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.model.ModelService)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:54.608 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'sessionService' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setSessionService(de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionService)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.order.strategies.ordercloning.impl.DefaultOrderPartOfMembersCloningStrategy.setSessionService(de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.session.SessionService)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:54.672 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'txManager' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTxManager(org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.order.strategies.ordercloning.impl.DefaultOrderPartOfMembersCloningStrategy.setTxManager(org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager)]
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:56:54.795 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
INFO   | wrapper  | main    | 2017/02/08 10:57:02.107 | Wrapper Process has not received any CPU time for 1 seconds.  Extending timeouts.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:57:47.829 | WARN  [WrapperSimpleAppMain] [GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor] Invalid JavaBean property 'tenantScope' being accessed! Ambiguous write methods found next to actually used [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]: [public void de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.internal.service.AbstractBusinessService.setTenantScope(de.hybris.platform.spring.TenantScope)]
STATUS | wrapper  | main    | 2017/02/08 10:57:51.280 | CTRL-C trapped.  Shutting down.
STATUS | wrapper  | main    | 2017/02/08 10:57:51.389 | CTRL-C trapped.  Forcing immediate shutdown.
INFO   | jvm 1    | main    | 2017/02/08 10:57:52.053 | shutting down hybris registry..
```

Comment: Which Hybris version is this ? Keep in mind, that Hybris 6 requires Java 1.8

Comment: Hybris version is 4.8.7, I ever used Java 1.8, there occurred some errors. I think this has nothing to do with Java version.

Answer (score 0):

Hybris supports JRebel.

Here follows the documentation link for your version:
https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release4/How+to+Use+JRebel (requires an Hybris account)